# compare multiple method parameter length of controller in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller method which is accepting four arrays as parameters I want to check whether the length of each array is the same or not.  If so, proceed to save data otherwise I want to send an error to view.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Manage(DateTime[] date, decimal[] In, decimal[] Out, string[] desc, int masterid)
    {
        ViewBag.Messege; 
        using (var transaction = db.GetTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                if (date.Length == amtIn.Length == amtOut.Length == description.Length)
                {
                    
                   ViewBag.Messege = $"Records Got Saved"; 
                }
                else
                {
                   ViewBag.Messege = "No Reocrds Got Saved";
                }
                transaction.Complete();
                
                
                return RedirectToAction("Index", ViewBag.Messege);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Dispose();
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anybody help me to compare that array input length if it is equal or not

Comment: `if (a == b && b == c && c == d)`

Comment: `transaction.Dispose();
                throw ex;` The first line is unnecessary, The second should be `throw;`